# combine or intersect two arrays different length in php

Tags: php, arrays

First array is `$niz`:

```
Array (
  [Swansea] => 4
  [Stoke City] => 3
  [Sunderland] => 3
  [Southampton] => 5
  [Liverpool] => 3
  [Manchester United] => 2
  [Hull City] => 1
  [Tottenham] => 2
  [Newcastle Utd] => 1
  [Aston Villa] => 1
  [West Ham] => 2
  [Crystal Palace] => 3
  [Chelsea] => 3
)
```

Second array is $niz1:

```
Array (
  [Stoke City] => 2
  [Sunderland] => 2
  [Liverpool] => 1
  [Hull City] => 1
  [Tottenham] => 1
  [Manchester United] => 1
  [Newcastle Utd] => 1
  [Crystal Palace] => 3
  [Chelsea] => 1
```

)

How to combine these arrays to get `$niz2` (keys are ordered like array `$niz1` and values are from matching array `$niz`) like:

`$niz2`:

```
Array (
  [Stoke City] => 3
  [Sunderland] => 3
  [Liverpool] => 3
  [Hull City] => 1
  [Tottenham] => 2
  [Manchester United] => 2
  [Newcastle Utd] => 1
  [Crystal Palace] => 3
  [Chelsea] => 3
```

)

I tried with function `array_merge()` but I get empty values and I tried with `array_intersect_key()`.

Comment: Show the code you tried otherwise this looks like a "write my code for me" question.

Comment: Comment with reason is good, but please vote to close such questions right away. If problem persists, he'll ask again with better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this**

```
foreach ($niz1 as $k=>$n)
{
    if(in_array($k,$niz1))
    {
        $niz2[$k]=$niz[$k];
    }

}
print_r($niz2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$temp = array_intersect_key($niz, $niz1);

foreach ($niz1 as $k => $v) {
    $niz2[$k] = $temp[$k];
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't satisfy the "keys are ordered like array $niz1" part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
//(overwrites the values of $niz1 with those of $niz2)
$bif=array_merge($niz1,$niz);  

//(removes everything from $bif that is not in $niz1)
$result=array_intersect($niz1,$bif);
```